# Is their a way to make the for loop go through every item in the array?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer game but the collision code with the objects in the world isn't working as intended. I'm using the collide2D library to help with collision.

The issue is that the collision code is being executed but only for the last item in the "objs" array. When I load the game the character ignores all the blocks/items and only collides with the last object in the array. objCount is just a global variable that lets me change it when I add more objects.

I know I can write the code out for every item in the array but I was hoping to condense it into a loop.

```
objCount = 20 //the number of items in the array
    
for (let i = 0; i < objCount; i++){
    if (collideRectRect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.w, player1.h, objs[i].x, objs[i].y, objs[i].s, objs[i].s)){
        minPh = objs[i].y-player1.h;
    }
    else{
        minPh = minH-player1.h;
    }
}
```

Comment: try using  `for(var i=0 ; i<objs.length;i++)` . I've got a feeling objCount isn't what you think it is, I don't know unless you post all of your code however

Comment: you could also try using a `objs.forEach` loop which will iterate over each of the objects in the objs array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with this library but I have 2 recommendations. First, maybe find a way to only detect collisions with on-screen items. Second, outsource your logic to a function so it can preserve the `i` index

```
// get world bounds
let world = document.querySelector('#world').getBoundingClientRect();

function testCollision(i) {
  // test for on screen
  if (objs[i].x < 0 || objs[i].x > world.width) return;
  
  if (collideRectRect(player1.x, player1.y, player1.w, player1.h, objs[i].x, objs[i].y, objs[i].s, objs[i].s)) {
    minPh = objs[i].y - player1.h;
    // react to collision
  } else {
    minPh = minH - player1.h;
  }
}
for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) testCollision(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the array.forEach method for arrays. It makes your life a lot easier and allows you to focus on what you want to do for each element in the array, and is a more 'functional' approach to programming, some consider to be better. Below I have shared an example of the forEach loop you could apply in your case:

```
objs.forEach((obj) => {
  // 'obj' is an element in your 'objs' Array, here we define what
  // we want to do "forEach" element
  if (
    collideRectRect(
      player1.x,
      player1.y,
      player1.w,
      player1.h,
      obj.x,
      obj.y,
      obj.s,
      obj.s
    )
  ) {
    // IF True do this
    minPh = objs[i].y - player1.h;
  } else {
    // ELSE do this
    minPh = minH - player1.h;
  }
});
```

hopefully this helps